# Why doesn't IEnumerable?.First() work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, null-conditional-operator

When I try to use ?.First() on an enumerable object, it throws the error "sequence contains no elements" when the object contains no items.

I recognise that the solution is to use .FirstOrDefault(), but I don't understand why my original effort doesn't work.  Am I misunderstanding something or is it just 'one of those things'?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is not null in your case, just that the sequence does not contains anything. If your IEnumerable object was null, then even `FirstOrDefault` would have thrown error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An empty sequence is not `null`, it's an actual object that simply has no items in it.  `?.` doesn't call the member in question *if the expression is `null`*, which it's not, so `First` is called, and `First` throws an exception when it is passed an empty sequence.

Comment: Of course, it seems obvious now that it's explained! I made an assumption about the purpose of this operator without really thinking about it.

Answer (score 5):

The null conditional operator (?) tests for null before performing a member access operation. The empty sequence is not null, it just contains no elements. So when you call First() it rightly fails, because there is no first element.

Answer (score 4):

Because empty collection is not `null`.

Answer (score 3):

First() explicitly throws an exception when the sequence contains no elements.  FirstOrDefault() gives `null` if there are no elements (edit: or rather, it gives a default value, which for reference types is `null`).  What would you want First() to return from an empty sequence?

Comment: "FirstOrDefault() gives null if there are no elements" is not true. It will give `default(TSource)` which is not necessarily `null`; this is only true if `TSource` is a reference type.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  That is an important distinction.

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN documentation:

```
    int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null   
    Customer first = customers?[0];  // null if customers is null  
    int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();  // null if customers, the first         customer, or Orders is null
```

Therefore, if your collection is not null, then the runtime will try to return the first element. Since the collection is empty and you didn't use **FirstOrDefault**, an exception is thrown.

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx